# Connect Stripe to Firebase Database

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, server, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

In advance, I apologize for unqualified questions.  I have not been in the programming world for so long and am currently experimenting with different things.  I have developed an IOS application in Swift that is connected to a Firebase Realtime Database.  I would now like to implement Stripe in my app.  However, since Stripe wants to access a server, I wonder what kind of server I need to do that. I think I also need to understand Cloud Functions. What do I need to learn? Is it really complex to connect Stripe to Firebase Database and is there any way I do not need to create an external server?

Answer (score 1):

You will indeed need a trusted environment to run the payment processing code. This can be your development machine, a server you control, or something serverless like Cloud Functions. Recommending one of the other is off topic here on Stack Overflow, but any of them can work.

For a great introduction on adding payment processing to your app, with Cloud Functions, have a look at this video [Go serverless: manage payments in your apps](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JeyxolsJ3aE). The [server-side code for the payment processing](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/stripe) used in the talk is available on Github. If you prefer to read instead of watching video, you can read about the same approach in the blog post [Go serverless: Manage Payments in your Apps with Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/go-serverless-manage-payments-in-your-apps-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-3528cfad770).